# kile crashes at startup and has no debug symbols

Tags: 14.04, kile

kile has started crashing every time at startup. The KDE crash handler comes up but complains there are no debug symbols. There appears to be no -dbg package for kile.

```
I ran it with gdb and this is what I get.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/kile 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe2609700 (LWP 19388)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe1e08700 (LWP 19389)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd98e9700 (LWP 19390)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd90e8700 (LWP 19391)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd88e7700 (LWP 19392)]
[Thread 0x7fffd88e7700 (LWP 19392) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffd88e7700 (LWP 19394)]
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
kile(19381)/kdecore (KLibrary) findLibraryInternal: plugins should not have a 'lib' prefix: "libkonsolepart.so"
[New Thread 0x7fffc40ef700 (LWP 19396)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc2db1700 (LWP 19412)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff204ebe6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is similar, but not the same.

After start of Kile, I typed a letter in the editor (last edited file opened), and the application crashed immediately. If instead of typing a letter, I opened a new file and started typing in it, Kile is OK, but when I come back to the older file, again, after typing a letter it crashes.

I did not search for any details in reports and can't repeat the problem now.

Possible solutions: I think once I invoked the PDFLaTeX or LaTeX compilation as the first step, and after they had finished, the editing worked. Another time, that solution did not help, but running *sudo kile* or *kile* from CLI removed the problem. I do not understand why, but it helped.